# Unit test: using a function from the program you are testing

Tags: python, python-unittest

In the program I am testing, I have 2 functions: a signUp() that creates a user in the database and a userExists() that tests whether a user exists. However, for the unit test, I need to assert that the user "nonExistingUser" exists after signing him up:

```
import sql #file I am testing
import unittest

class test_sql(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_userExists(self):
        self.assertTrue(sql.userExists("existingUser"))

   def test_signUp(self):
        sql.signUp("nonExistingUser","password")
        self.assertTrue(sql.userExists("nonExistingUser"))
```

Is using a function from a file that I am testing bad practice? Should I create a copy of the userExists() just for the unit test or keep it as is? Or should I do something else?

Comment: The whole point of testing is to test your code, meaning that you have to call it in your test. You can use mocks to replace parts of your code and other techniques to be able to test only the needed functionality, but that is a large topic. I would suggest you read up on unit testing.

Comment: so I shouldn't use the same function, right?

Comment: No, you should! Maybe I wasn't clear - by "you have to call your code in your test" I'm referring to your production code.